# angularjs ngRepeat directive to not trigger digest for other items in the list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It seems like ngRepeat triggers the watches on any list item after changing one of them. I'm already using track by so that doesn't seem to help.

Here's my template:

```
div(ng-repeat="poll in polls track by poll._id")
  poll(poll="poll")

.poll
  .title(ng-if="!poll.closed") {{poll.title}}
  .btn(ng-click="poll.closed = true") Change poll
  {{someExpensiveComputation(poll._id)}}
```

javascript:

```
.directive('poll', function($rootScope, $modal) {
  return {
    replace: false,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      poll: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/tmpl/poll',
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
      $scope.someExpensiveComputation = function (id) { ... }
    }
  }
});
```

It seems like whenever a poll item is changed the someExpensiveComputation function runs for all the polls, and 3x each time. How do I get it to not do that? It should only trigger the watchers for that directive. I think that should be possible.

Thanks.

Comment: How does the poll change ? Who changes it ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem hi, thanks. I edited the question with an example of poll editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All **[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**-expressions are processed (evaluated) multiple times in every $digest loop.
So, it is a good practice to keep the **[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**-expression as simple as possible (in terms of computational complexity).

(BTW, using `{{...}}` in your view creates a **[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**.)

If `someExpensiveComputation()` is...computationally expensive, you don't want to evaluate it every time, but only when it might produce a different result. It depends on the implementation of the function, but assuming its result relies only on the properties of each poll, then you could **[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)** the poll and call the expensive function whenever it is changed:

```
.poll
...
{{expensivelyComputedValue}}

.directive('poll', function($rootScope, $modal) {
    return {
        ...
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            function someExpensiveComputation(id) { ... }

            scope.expensivelyComputedValue = someExpensiveComputation(scope.poll.id);
            scope.$watch('poll', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue === oldValue) { return; }
                scope.expensivelyComputedValue = someExpensiveComputation(scope.poll.id);
            }, true);
        }
    }
});
```

Of course, if the result of the expensive computation depends only on a specific property of poll (and not the entire object), it suffices to **[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)** this property only, thus keeping your **[watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)**-expression even more "light-weight". E.g.:

```
scope.$watch('poll.closed', function (...) {...});
```

Comment: Thanks is there no way to get that behavior by using templates instead of manually watching in the controller? A local watcher of sorts that doesn't react to higher scope changes?

Comment: I am afraid there isn't such a away. If you know for sure that the data will only change when you press a button, you could incorporate the call to `someExpensiveComputation()` into the button click-handler.

Comment: Wow ! What's the downvote for ? Where's my accompanying comment ?